# file_put_contents() not working

Tags: php

I want to save the contents in the file in `order.dat` and `now` I'm using this PHP script:

```
<?php
$a_str = array( 
  "orderid"=>"175", 
  "txnid"=>"RC456456456", 
  "date"=>"54156456465", 
  "amount"=>"109$" 
); 

$file = 'order.txt';
$contents = implode(PHP_EOL, $a_str);
//$contents = $orderid.'|'.$txnid.'|'.$date.'|'.$amount;
$contents .= PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($file, $contents);
print("|$contents|");
?>
```

How it is possible to save the data in `order.dat` file in this format?

```
175|RC456456456|54156456465|109$|
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter should be the data: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

e.g.

```
$data = $orderid.'|'.$txnid.'|'.$date.'|'.$amount;
file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

It would probably be better to store the line data in an array and then implode it around the `|` character.